# Render basic html with react and spring mvc

Tags: spring, reactjs, model-view-controller

I have a spring mvc app running . Started learning react, thought i will plugin a basic react page from inside a spring controller.

Here is what i did:
created a react app using create-react-app , in the package.json under build, provided command to mv the contents under build (static files, index.html etc) to src/main/webapp/frontend - so that they can be accesed by a view file(jsp) which is under the webapp.

`"build": "react-scripts build && rm -rf ../src/main/resources/frontend/build/  && rm -rf ../src/main/webapp/frontend/ && mv build/ ../src/main/webapp/frontend/",`

In order to execute npm install and run build, provided these as part of exec-maven-plugin build .
Created a view file , and referred the frontend/index.html (which is copied as part of npm build) from it .

Everything is fine, but it looks weird copying files to webapp directory.

Is there any other suggestion ?
1.Can i copy the  js files to the target/classes/customfolder ?

2.Instead of putting the html path inside the view, can i return an html string from the controller (which will refer to static files copied in step 1 )

Any suggestion is welcome

thanks